# Pause/Break key on modern keyboards

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there still a use for this key in modern operating systems? I know back in the days of the rapid fire `dir /s` on ten thousand files in DOS 5.5 this key was indispensable, but is it needed anymore? If not, can I remap it to do something else? If so, what?

Comment: I use as my media Play/Pause button

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Windows, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> opens up the System Properties window.  Not exactly relevant to what the key was originally designed for, but still quite useful!

Comment: One use was to interrupt to the command line (i.e. so it would pause/break processes). Generally we just use `Ctrl+C` for *killing* command line statements nowadays (this is also quite a relic, since it does not "copy" selected text as is otherwise the universal expectation today).

Answer (score 17):

The <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key can also be used during boot to pause a POST screen so you can read it before continuing.  I find it useful when I'm trying to double check that something is detected properly by the BIOS.

Comment: ok thats a given.  I figure any remapping i do wouldn't effect that

Comment: For sure.  You could remap it to anything you want without affecting its functionality at boot time.

Answer (score 16):

Here are a couple common keyboard alternatives (please feel free to contribute to this list)

- **General** -<kbd>Pause</kbd>
- **General** -<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>
- **Lenovo** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
- **Lenovo** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- **Lenovo** - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- **Logitech** - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- **Samsung** - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- **HewlettPackard** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>
- **HewlettPackard** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right-Shift</kbd>
- **Dell** - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- **Dell** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- **Framework** - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Ctrl + Fn + Pause works for Break on my Dell Precision M6800 laptop.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the original question, this was what I was looking for when google sent me here. Thanks. Also added to the list.

Comment: Also on Logitech Ergo K860, `Fn + WM/SC` (Windows Menu / scroll lock key in top right corner) works as break key.  For `Ctrl+Break == Ctrl+Fn+WM/SL`

Comment: Fn+B on this Dell Precision 5501 according to https://en.key-test.ru/ Adding Win opens Windows properties.

Comment: Both Fn + B and Fn + S also work on my Dell

Comment: thanks man great help

Answer (score 10):

Windows supports remapping keys itself: [howtoogeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> is still useful on the command prompt to send a break character; but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is a little easier.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever have to configure equipment using a terminal emulator, you might wish you had kept the key.  You need that key to halt the cisco boot process to recover the IOS or the configuration.  I have had to do this to get into cisco devices people have forgotten the password on quite a few times.

Now if you never ever do this sort of thing then you have no disincentive to remap the key.  I find it more practical to map key combinations that you never ever use.  This is particularly the case in multi-clipboard apps I have used doing repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 4):

The command prompt still accepts this key in XP, as other OSes.

Answer (score 4):

You can remap any key to do just about anything if you install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: this question is not windows-specific.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> is a useful shortcut to toggle between full-screen and windowed remote desktop sessions.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> is a useful shortcut for stopping a build in Visual Studio.